# Saving text color to a text file in python?

Tags: python, stdout

I am wondering, is there any way to save the color of text when printing stdout to a text file? Here is a snippet of code for example:

```
import sys, time, shutil

sys.stdout = open('testytest.txt', 'w')
print "\033[0;32mSome text"

time.sleep(1)

#"Some text" should still be colored when reprinted
with open('testytest.txt', 'r') as testfile:
     shutil.copyfileobj(testfile, sys.stdout)
```

So, once again, is there any way to save color when stdout is being saved to a text file? Or is it already saved?

Comment: Haven't gotten a chance to try, on a trip without access to my computer. I asked this question because I am curious about it.

Comment: Depending on your downstream application, probably more universal to use HTML tags to format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you print the escape characters as well.

So if you save the data that is printed to the stdout like:

```
python somescript.py > somefile
```

That file will contain the escape chars as well.

This to conclude: **it is already saved**. Instructions to modify the color actually don't exist. The program simply writes a binary stream and some shell visual programs interpret this as command to color.

Comment: So I would just print the raw string to the file?

Comment: @TheNotGoodAtCodeGuy - Sure, but whatever you open the file in will need to interpret the escapes as being colors for you to see anything other than the raw string. (And I don't know of any program that'll do that).

Comment: Indeed. For instance most people argue that `\n` is a newline. Now most programs will indeed interpret this as a new line. What is in fact written is a binary `0x0a`. And most programs will *interpret* this as a newline. But it is perfectly possible to design your own character set where the newline is for instance `0x33`.